# matplotlib: coloring line plots by iteration-dependent gray scale

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, plot, interpolation

Relative programming newbie here. I have trouble figuring out how to plot interpolated functions over a series of iterations, where as the iteration index increases, the plot would go from black to gradually lighter shades of grey.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

for t in np.arange(0.,2., 0.4):
    x = np.linspace(0.,4, 100)
    y = np.sin(x-2*t) + 0.01 * np.random.normal(size=x.shape)
    yint = interp1d(x, y)
    plt.plot(x, yint(x))

plt.show()
```

produces
[image]

I would like the blue sinusoidal function to be black, and the rest becomes lighter and greyer as t increases (to the right). How would I do that?

Thank you all for your generous help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot

E.g. you can set `plt.plot(x, yint(x), color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))` for a gray line. You can set the values up however you like (0.0 is black, 1.0 is white). A simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

for t in np.arange(0.,2., 0.4):
    x = np.linspace(0.,4, 100)
    y = np.sin(x-2*t) + 0.01 * np.random.normal(size=x.shape)
    yint = interp1d(x, y)
    print t
    col = (t/2.0, t/2.0, t/2.0)
    plt.plot(x, yint(x), color=col)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's fantastic! Thanks! One question, however: Looking through documentations and playing around with the code, I still can't figure out the line `col = (t/2.0, t/2.0, t/2.0)`. Why does it contain 3 identical elements? What does each refer to (e.g., starting color, ending color, etc.)? It also appears that I can add more t/n inside the parenthesis indefinitely.. What's going on here?

Comment: An element like `(2, 4, 5.0, "something")` is a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). It can have an arbitrary number of elements. In this case we are setting an `RGB` tuple. The first number is the red intensity, the second the blue, the third the green. When these are equal you get gray. So we are creating a tuple representing a gray colour and then using that for the line color. You can see different options for how to do this in the link I gave if you scroll down to the paragraph beginning "by default".

Comment: If things like tuples are unfamiliar to you, I recommend taking a little bit of time out to go through the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), the first five sections or so at least.

Comment: The "RGB tuple" is a thing that the `plot` function recognises - in this context it will treat a tuple of numbers as instructions to set the color accordingly. It's not a feature of Python in general, in case my comment made it sound like it was.

Comment: Thank you Mr E! Your answers are tremendously helpful. I will start on the Python Tutorial as recommended!