# Matplotlib: coloring line plots by iteration-dependent (non-gray) colour scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a plot with the pairs of trajectories that closely follow each other, here is how they currently look:
[image]

I would like less recent pairs of trajectories to be lighter in shade, and more recent ones darker in shade.

One of them could go through the gray palette like in [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118258/matplotlib-coloring-line-plots-by-iteration-dependent-gray-scale), however as there has to be a pair of these and I want to be able to distinguish between the two, I need a way to rotate through the shades of yet another colour (a single colour, not the default multi-colour rotation matplotlib uses).

Does anyone has any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a color map. A list of available colormaps is available here: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Once you choose your colormaps you can use:

```
cmap1 = plt.cm.get_cmap('Reds')
cmap2 = plt.cm.get_cmap('Blues')
```

Then, you can select a color by `color1 = cmap1(t)`. note that `t` must be between 0 and 1, so if it is not, you must shift it and scale. If you know your min and max times, you can use the `Normalize` class:

```
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=tmin, vmax=tmax)
color1 = cmap1(norm(t))
```